# Using a ContentPane's JComponent functionality

Tags: java, swing

Fred Swartz writes in a note on Java GUI programming (more specifically, about the best ways to access and use a component's ContentPane)

> ... if we get the predefined content pane [by invoking
>   `getContentPane()` on a `JFrame`], it turns out it's actually a
>   `JPanel`, but we really can't take advantage of the functionality that
>   was added by `JComponent`.

-- http://www.fredosaurus.com/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-60-contentpane.html

In this case, what prohibits someone from using the `JComponent` functionality of a `JPanel`? `JPanel` extends `JComponent`, so shouldn't `JPanel` have unhindered access to `JComponent`'s methods?

Answer (score 2):

Read further in his comments about using the returned Component:

If we downcast it to JPanel, we create fragile code that might break because the contract with getContentPane() is to return a Container, and there is no guarantee that future versions will actually continue to return a JPanel.

Comment: That bit explains why we shouldn't cast the returned JComponent to JPanel, in order to use JPanel's functionality, and not why JComponent functionality can't be used.